# Outer artifacts when using GL_LINEAR in Texture OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I success to generate the height map using texture in openGL. The full picture of this data is shown in the figure below. However, when I'm using GL_LINEAR option in my glTexParameteri (MinMag) it give me outer artifacts.

this is my glTexParameter

```
if (interpolate) {
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
}
else {
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
}

glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Here is my fragment shader code

```
    "varying vec2 tex;\n"
    "uniform int colorSizeI;\n"
    "uniform vec4 colorTable[512];\n"
    "uniform vec2 minmaxZ;\n"
    "uniform vec3 backgroundColor;\n"
    "uniform sampler2D diffuse;\n"
    "uniform float transparency;\n"
    "void main() {\n"
    "   float color = texture2D(diffuse, tex).r;\n"
    "   float h = (color - minmaxZ[0])/(minmaxZ[1] - minmaxZ[0]);\n"
    "   float colorSizeF = float(colorSizeI);\n"
    "   int i = 0;\n"
    "   float j = 0.0f;\n"
    "   vec3 base;\n"
    "   if (color == 0.0f) {\n"
    "       base = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);}\n"
    "   else if (color <= minmaxZ[0]) {\n"
    "       base = colorTable[0].xyz;}\n"
    "   else if (color >= minmaxZ[1]) {\n"
    "       base = colorTable[colorSizeI - 1].xyz;}\n"
    "   else { \n"
    "       while (h >= (j + 1.0f)/colorSizeF) {\n"
    "           i += 1;\n"
    "           j += 1.0f;}\n"
    "       base = mix(colorTable[i].xyz, colorTable[i+1].xyz, colorSizeF*(h - (j/colorSizeF)));}\n"
    "   gl_FragColor = vec4(base, transparency);\n"
    "}\n";
```

Here is the image when using GL_Nearest (everything is OK)
[image: using GL Nearest]

Here is the image when using GL_Linear (outer interpolated artifacts comes out)
[image: using GL Linear]

So, anyone know how to remove this artifacts ?

NB: The outer black color is consider the data also when color = 0.

Comment: clamp the edges `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` or `GL_CLAMP`

Comment: I used GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, I forgot to mention, the outer black color outside the square actually data also when the z = 0;  So I don't believe it's because the texturewrap.

Comment: you're going to have to provide all the `::glTexParameteri` calls so we can see what you're doing

Comment: what happens if you do `gl_FragColor = texture2D(diffuse, tex)`

Comment: I'm using texture to avoid using the vertices & indices (reduces memory).  In the texture (red) data is contain the heightmap that will be show in color based on the calculation in fragment shader.  So if I do `gl_FragColor = texture2D(diffuse, tex)` it won't display the data that I want to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fixed it with making an outer boundary with the value of interpolation of nearest pixels and put alpha = 0 for that.

It worked nicely, however it cost 2 times of original memory consumption since I need to store the alpha map also.

[image: final]

Comment: please post a picture of the final result

Comment: little bit blurry on the edge. But I can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your wrapping for the texture is currently GL_REPEAT. You should try another one.

GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT or GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE should work.

Comment: I used GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE, I forgot to mention, the outer black color outside the square actually data also when the z = 0;  So I don't believe it's because the texturewrap.

Comment: Ok, then maybe this line is the problem: base = colorTable[colorSizeI - 1].xyz;} Looks wrong but can't help you more because I don't know the uniform values.

Comment: I prepare buffer in `uniform vec4 colorTable[512]` because have some option for my colorTable and every option of that has different number of color.  The `colorSizeI - 1` is to make sure if the height more than some value, color will be the last valid value in colorTable.  So I tried to change it like you suggest, but the interpolation artifacts still there.

Comment: I think now I understand what you're trying to do: you have a texture with values from 0.0 to 1.0 for height but this texture has a border with value 1.0 = maximum height. OpenGL is now interpolating these values in the middle along the border with 1.0. - Looks like you have to remove the border from the texture or stay with GL_NEAREST.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because of interpolating from "null color" to actual colors in the colr table. To put it short: you can't do that. The concept is broken. Back to the drawing board.

The simplest solution is not having null color, limiting the quad to only the valid area, and doing GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE as others suggested.

A trickier way is setting GL_NEAREST and then writing the linear sampling yourself in the shader, sampling the texture with `tex` plus some offsets (manhattan distance should be fine) and skip the null color when blending (the skip part is what is missing from your original concept). The tricky part is getting the offsets right.

Comment: Could use "transparent (alpha = 0.0)" as the null color, and then the predefined blend functions should work again.

Comment: Sadly not. It would at best remove half a texelwidth of artifacts but the null color would still bleed into non-null texels, e.g. top of top-left texel would turn from red to yellow whereas zufry wants it to blue to the border.

Comment: For the area with black color, I will put alpha = 0 there.  I show it in black color for make thing easier to explain here.  And also the area with black color it has height = 0 and it goes into these `if (color == 0.0f) {base = vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);}`.  @Andreas: so in the end it's a limitation of GL_LINEAR ?  can you give reading material about method your suggest ?

Comment: @zufryy It is not a method I know of from before. If you want to read something check the documentation for GL_LINEAR and GL_NEAREST. Make sure you understand why you get the erroneous image output, and try figure out an algorithm that satisfies youy requirements from there. Good luck.

Comment: @Andreas:  The things is when using GL_LINEAR when the pixel try to calculate interpolation and there is null point in the neighbour pixels it will have this kind of situation.  Thus, I just make "dummy" point as an outer boundaries then apply alpha = 0 there.